# Extracting a file extension from a given path in Rust idiomatically

Tags: path, rust, filenames, file-extension

I am trying to extract the extension of a file from a given String path.

The following piece of code works, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner and more **idiomatic Rust way** to achieve this:

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {

    fn get_extension_from_filename(filename: String) -> String {

        //Change it to a canonical file path.
        let path = Path::new(&filename).canonicalize().expect(
            "Expecting an existing filename",
        );

        let filepath = path.to_str();
        let name = filepath.unwrap().split('/');
        let names: Vec<&str> = name.collect();
        let extension = names.last().expect("File extension can not be read.");
        let extens: Vec<&str> = extension.split(".").collect();

        extens[1..(extens.len())].join(".").to_string()
    }

    assert_eq!(get_extension_from_filename("abc.tar.gz".to_string()) ,"tar.gz" );
    assert_eq!(get_extension_from_filename("abc..gz".to_string()) ,".gz" );
    assert_eq!(get_extension_from_filename("abc.gz".to_string()) , "gz");

}
```

Comment: So you want to get everything after the leftmost dot? That would give the wrong result for e.g. "Version 1.2.txt"

Comment: @interjay, yes and therefore  I maintain a hashmap of allowed extensions, therefore `2.txt` would panic. My intention is to extract a possible extension,  in a generic way and compare against allowed-extensions hashmap.

Comment: `.tar.gz` isn't a standalone extension, it's a `.gz` file, and when uncompressed you get a `.tar` file. You should follow the same process. Extract the extension and the non-extension parts, and recursively process the non-extension part pulling extensions off of it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In idiomatic Rust the return type of a function that can fail should be an `Option` or a `Result`. In general, functions should also accept slices instead of `String`s and only create a new `String` where necessary. This reduces excessive copying and heap allocations.

You can use the provided `extension()` method and then convert the resulting `OsStr` to a `&str`:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn get_extension_from_filename(filename: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    Path::new(filename)
        .extension()
        .and_then(OsStr::to_str)
}

assert_eq!(get_extension_from_filename("abc.gz"), Some("gz"));
```

Using `and_then` is convenient here because it means you don't have to unwrap the `Option<&OsStr>` returned by `extension()` and deal with the possibility of it being `None` before calling `to_str`. I also could have used a lambda `|s| s.to_str()` instead of `OsStr::to_str` - it might be a matter of preference or opinion as to which is more idiomatic.

Notice that both the argument `&str` and the return value are references to the original string slice created for the assertion. The returned slice cannot outlive the original slice that it is referencing, so you may need to create an owned `String` from this result if you need it to last longer.

Answer (score 16):

What's more idiomatic than using Rust's [builtin method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.extension) for it?

```
Path::new(&filename).extension()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I think this example would fail:
`assert_eq!(get_extension_from_filename("abc.tar.gz".to_string()) ,"tar.gz" );`

Comment: @Sokio Oh, I missed that.