# Check if a file is of a given type

Tags: rust, file-type

How can I fix this function? I think that I have to convert the name to `String` but then I would have to convert it back to `str` to use `ends_with`. Should I use another function to do that?

```
use walkdir::{DirEntry};

fn is_filetype(entry: &DirEntry, _type: &str) -> bool {
    entry.file_name()
        .to_str()
        .to_lowercase()
        .map(|s| s.ends_with(_type))
        .unwrap_or(false)
}

error[E0599]: no method named `to_lowercase` found for enum `Option` in the current scope
  --> src/bin/parse_torrent.rs:45:10
   |
45 |         .to_lowercase()
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Option<&str>`
```

Comment: `.to_str()` returns an `Option` so you need to `unwrap` or `expect` it before calling `to_lowercase` on it: `entry.file_name().to_str().unwrap().to_lowercase()`

Comment: Note that lowercasing the comparing is **not** a perfect check for Unicode equality ignoing casing.

Comment: @joshmeranda `.unwrap()` is not a good idea here: better something like `entry.file_name().map_or(false, |f| f.to_str().to_lowercase().ends_with(_type))`

Comment: @ChayimFriedman good idea

Comment: @ShadowRanger I assume that was intended to be `Option::map` not `Iterator::map`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292067/493729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix the code provided in the question would probably be to use `map_or` like @ChayimFriedman suggests in the comments.

```rust
fn is_filetype(entry: &DirEntry, _type: &str) -> bool {
    entry
        .file_name()
        .to_str()
        .map_or(false, |s| s.to_lowercase().ends_with(_type))
}
```

However if we expand this to also look at other approaches there are a few more options.
In the past, one approach I used was to use the built in `.extension()` method.

```rust
if path.extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) == Some("txt") {
    do_the_thing();
}
```

However, we can probably do better. After a bit of tinkering, here is what I came up with.

```rust
pub trait FileExtension {
    fn has_extension<S: AsRef<str>>(&self, extensions: &[S]) -> bool;
}

impl<P: AsRef<Path>> FileExtension for P {
    fn has_extension<S: AsRef<str>>(&self, extensions: &[S]) -> bool {
        if let Some(ref extension) = self.as_ref().extension().and_then(OsStr::to_str) {
            return extensions
                .iter()
                .any(|x| x.as_ref().eq_ignore_ascii_case(extension));
        }

        false
    }
}
```

This new version gives us a few extra features. We can check for multiple extension types and it gives us more flexibility in what types it uses.

```rust
// original
if is_filetype(&dir_entry, "txt") {}

// Alternate
if dir_entry.path().has_extension(&["txt"]) {}

// We can also check for multiple extensions
if dir_entry.path().has_extension(&["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp"]) {}
```

That being said, there are some pros/cons:

- Files with extensions like `.tar.gz` will be read as having an extension of `gz`.
- Files with names starting with a period will not be misread as extensions (Ex: The folder `~/.ssh` is correctly identified as having no extension).
- "magic bytes" at the start of a file are not checked for file types where they are required.